# html front end on joomla based site

Tags: php, html, joomla, adobe, muse

thanks in advance for any and all suggestions.

I am trying to put a temp site built in Adobe Muse in place of the existing Joomla site
and I am wondering if in doing that, I can till link to the original Joomla site.
eg: as an "archive" page perhaps.

If not, I'd still like to be able to do that without damaging the original Joomla site itself.
The original Joomla site doesn't need to be seen (online).

I don't want to work in Joomla, I don't want a Joomla plug-in.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Just move the joomla site to a subdirectory, eg site.com/oldjoomlasite/

Comment: I'd like to be able to keep the site live if possible.

Answer (score 0):

If your Adobe Muse website has an index.html (instead of index.php), then this will work for you, all you need to do is to ensure that your .htaccess file first processes the index.html file, and then the index.php file. So, in order to access your Joomla website, your link should be http://www.yourwebiste.com/index.php . Here's the line that you should add in your .htaccess file:

```
DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
```